# Powershell as a java process on a unix system, output not displayed from cmdlet

Tags: java, powershell

I am writing an implementation for a powershell client. This implementation is in java. The JVM is running on a UNIX system. I need to be able to create an object `PowerShellClient` and have it spawn a process that opens powershell and allows me access to its stdin, stdout, and stderr so that I can invoke commands in said powershell session and observe their output.

I have already tried [jpowershell](https://github.com/profesorfalken/jPowerShell) and this implementation works great, but has a limitation: If you try to invoke a cmdlet that writes output multiple times, all of the output is not obtained, and the output is not entirely read. It seems to be terminated after the first `Write-Output`

```java
        PowerShell pwsh = PowerShell.openSession();
        String out = pwsh.executeCommand(
            "for($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++){Write-Output $i; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}")
            .getCommandOutput();

        System.out.println(out);
```

Produces the following:

```
0
```

So. I took it upon myself to implement something, I decided to implement it in such a way that it would wait for the prompt `>>>` to appear in STDOUT. Only when the prompt is seen will reading be stopped, and another command allowed to execute. However, I already have a **Problem:** **Output from cmdlets that output powershell objects is not even seen in stdout.** Here is some code

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class PowerShellClient {
    private PrintWriter stdin;
    private BufferedReader stderr;
    private BufferedReader stdout;
    private Process powerShellProcess;
    private Thread readErrThread;
    private Thread readOutThread;

    public PowerShellClient() throws IOException {
        powerShellProcess = new ProcessBuilder("powershell", "-nol", "-noe").start();

        stdout = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));

        stderr = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));

        stdin = new PrintWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(
                new BufferedOutputStream(
                    powerShellProcess.getOutputStream())),
                    true);

        readOutThread = new Thread(() -> {
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println("[STDOUT]: " + line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        readErrThread = new Thread(() -> {
            String line;
            try {
                while(null != (line = stderr.readLine()))
                    System.out.println("[STDERR]: " + line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        readErrThread.start();
        readOutThread.start();
    }

    public void executeCommand(String aRawCmd) {
        stdin.println(aRawCmd);
    }
}
```

And the use case:

```java
PowerShellClient client = new PowerShellClient();
client.executeCommand("Get-Process");
```

Produces the following:

```
[STDOUT]: >>> Get-Process
[STDOUT]: 
[STDOUT]:
```

while this use case:

```java
PowerShellClient client = new PowerShellClient();
client.executeCommand("for($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) { Write-Output $i; Start-Sleep 1}");
```

produces the following:

```
[STDOUT]: >>> for($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++) { Write-Output $i; Start-Sleep 1}
[STDOUT]: 0
[STDOUT]: 1
[STDOUT]: 2
[STDOUT]: 3
[STDOUT]: 4
[STDOUT]: 5
[STDOUT]: 6
[STDOUT]: 7
[STDOUT]: 8
[STDOUT]: 9
```

**My Question is this**:
Why is this happening? What is causing the output not to be observed, from a cmdlet that normally produces 10s of lines of output? I think it has something to do with the fact that the output from the cmdlets are passed to the powershell object engine, which somehow determines the size of your terminal and will format the output. I have already tried piping to `Out-String`, `Write-Out`, and `Write-Host`. I've even tried redirecting output to a file and then `cat`ing that file. No cigar, the file has no contents (except for a new \n).

Am I missing some configuration or something?

Version of powershell installed on UNIX system:
PowerShell 6.2.2

Comment: If you want powershell to use the same console that Java uses, use [`processBuilder.inheritIO(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--), and don't handle the 3 streams in Java.

Comment: Why are you doing this? powershell on java and linux sounds terrible.

Comment: For automation purposes. I need to remote into windows machines to perform commands from a Linux environment, from an application that is in java

Comment: Does it work if you pipe to `Out-String`?

Comment: No, this did not work either. However I was able to solve the problem. It was not easily reproducible in other environments, the solution was to re-install with some dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was not found, but I did find a solution.

The solution is to uninstall powershell, and re-install with several dependencies:
`omi`,  `gssntlmssp`, and `krb5-workstation`

```sh
#! /bin/bash

#install pwsh
sudo curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft.repo
sudo yum install -y powershell

#get epel repository
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

#install dependencies
sudo yum install -y omi gssntlmssp krb5-workstation

#restart omid
sudo systemctl restart omid

#create symlink for powershell
sudo ln -s /opt/microsoft/powershell/6/pwsh /usr/bin/powershell
```